# Cant show data from SQL Server - Query wont work

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to get some data out of a SQL Database and show them in a dropdown menu. Show the data from the DB is not a problem, but there is a problem with the dropdown menu.

My code so far:

```
            <?php
            include 'config.php';  

            $sql = "SELECT car FROM [dbo].[car_available]";

            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");

            while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo '<option value="'.$data['car'].'">';
                echo $data['car']; 
                echo "</option>";
            }

            ?>
```

The result is the "Couldn't execut query" message and I dont know why.
The config.php should be fine, as said a normal read out works.

Comment: You need to look at the error that is returned.

Comment: What does `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));` return if you use this instead of `..die("Couldn't execut query")`? The `$conn` variable must be initialized before the `sqlsrv_query()` call.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I get no "real" Error, just the comment from die()

Comment: @Zhorov:
$conn is initialized in the config.php
The output from your die():
Array ([0] => Array([0] => 42S02[SQLSTATE] => 42S02[1] => 208[code] => 208[2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ung�ltiger Objektname (this means something like "invalid object name"

Comment: @Fleksiu It seems the `[dbo].[car_available]` table doesn't exists or the current login doesn't have access to the table.